# ReactJS component doesn't re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a following example simple page:

**App.js**:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={ArticlesPage}/>
                <Route path='/search' component={SearchPage}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    };
};
```

**ArticlesPage.js**:

```
export default class ArticlesPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <Grid>
            <Row>
                <Col lg={12}>
                    <SearchBox/>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col lg={12}>
                    articles
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Grid>;
    }
};
```

**SearchPage.js**:

```
export default class SearchPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const {q} = queryString.parse(location.search);
        this.state = {
            query: q
        };
    }

    render() {
        return <Grid>
            <Row>
                <Col lg={12}>
                    <SearchBox/>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col lg={12}>
                    search {this.state.query}
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Grid>;
    }
};
```

**SearchBox.js**:

```
export default class SearchBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            q: ''
        };
    }

    onFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {router} = this.context;
        router.history.push('/search?q=' + this.state.q);
    };

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({q: e.target.value});
    };

    render() {
        return <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
            <Col lg={10} lgOffset={1}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <input type="text" name="q" id="q" ref={i => this.searchInput = i} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </FormGroup>
            </Col>
        </form>;
    }
};
```

And now, when I'm on the index page and type something in the input next send form, React render SearchPage.js and return correctly text `search *and what I typed*`, try again type something else in the input and send form, and React still show my previous text (not rerender).

What can be wrong with this simple page?

Comment: the result is returned on your searchpage.js right ?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif Indeed, in the `search {this.state.query}`, but as I said only on first time display correct query, every next time show only first.

Comment: I think the problem is that the `SearchPage` constructor is not called again when you're only changing the location's query.

Comment: You won't get a new instance of `SearchPage`. You will need to update the state with one of the component's lifecycle function `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: your issue is that the searchPage has no reason to update since your not updating the state of  `query`

Answer (score 0):

You have two different state variables, `query` on `<SearchPage />` and `q` on `<SearchBox />`. What you are changing is `q`, but the variable you are rendering as text is `query`.

You need to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and pass `query` as prop to `<SearchPage />`.

Comment: Thanks! After small refactor working. But there is a small issue. Now I have duplicated (in pages `ArticlesPage.js` and `SearchPage.js`) handler which is injected to a `SearchBox />` component. This component will be render on the n pages, and that duplication is a bad thing. Any other tips to refactor? Another think is a problem that I fetch data from server using `componentDidMount` method, that method is called only once.

Comment: There is absolutely no problem in calling the same handler in different components if they are changing the same variable. This is not a duplicate, on the contrary, you are reusing functions.

Comment: Maybe you don't understand me correctly. Look at this: https://pastebin.com/NcsA3jXp This method must be duplicated in two classes (now). It's ok? Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here's why the text on `SearchPage` doesn't update: the constructor runs *once* and updates the variable in state, but when the app re-renders, React, wanting to be efficient, sees that it would re-render a new `SearchPage` in the same spot as the previous one, so instead of replacing it, it keeps the state of the old one. Because of this, `SearchPage`'s state still keeps the old `q` variable.

Here's how you can fix it: make your `SearchPage` accept the search query as a prop, and render that.

```
class SearchPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col lg={12}>
            <SearchBox />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col lg={12}>search {this.props.query}</Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}
```

In the parent, where the route for it is being rendered, use a render function, take the props of it, parse the actual query from `props.location.search`, and pass it directly to `SearchPage`.

```
<Route
  path="/search"
  render={props => <SearchPage query={getSearchQuery(props.location.search)} />}
/>

// utility function to keep things clean
function getSearchQuery(locationSearch) {
  return queryString.parse(locationSearch.slice(1)).q
}
```

[Here's a working demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/ww67l262vw)

Comment: It's not a pretty solution because of the wrapping every Route. This search box, will be using on n pages. That what's worked for me is: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html Maybe you have other tips?

Comment: You could use the `component={SearchPage}` approach, then read `this.props.location.search` inside of the `SearchPage` component, though I'm not a fan of that, since it's less clear how all of the props and such are flowing through the app. You could also split the render function itself out as well. Plenty of ways to make it look pretty, if that's your main issue. Should always work regardless of wherever that SearchBox is used